# Are both APT and APT-GET both different repositories?

Tags: apt, gnome, 20.04, repository

I always wonder if APT and APT-GET are both different repositories? Are they different repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different applications (but lots of overlap).

Repositories are defined in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.*

All apt-based applications, including apt, apt-get, aptitude, and Synaptic use the same sources.